# UITextFieldDelegate Swift crash (function signature specialization)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, option-type

I know what `function signature specialization` means. I have already fixed two other occurences of ObjC Cocoa sending me nils despite Swift declared non-optionality. I attempted to fix this one the same way, but it persists.

```
Selector name found in current argument registers: release

function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of SpecificTextField.shouldChangeCharactersInRange (__C._NSRange, replacementString : Swift.String) -> Swift.Bool (SpecificTextField.swift:0)
SpecificTextField.shouldChangeCharactersInRange (__C._NSRange, replacementString : Swift.String) -> Swift.Bool (SpecificTextField.swift:91)
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead and Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of MyController.textField (__ObjC.UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange : __C._NSRange, replacementString : Swift.String) -> Swift.Bool (MyController.swift:645)
@objc MyController.textField (__ObjC.UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange : __C._NSRange, replacementString : Swift.String) -> Swift.Bool (MyController.swift:0)
...
```

**MyController.swift**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
  if isOptionalObjectNil(string) {
    return false
  }
  return specificTextField?.shouldChangeCharactersInRange(range, replacementString: string) ?? true
}
```

**SpecificTextField.swift**

```
class SpecificTextField: UITextField
{
  func shouldChangeCharactersInRange(range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    ...
  }      
}
```

`isOptionalObjectNil` is a global function which successfuly mitigated other `function signature specialization` crashes for me (and i have a hybrid ObjC/Swift test case for it) :

```
public func isOptionalObjectNil(testable: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
  return testable == nil
}
```

If crash report is to be trusted, the delegate is getting something nil. I decided that it could be only `string`, as `range` is passed by value and `textField` is not used (acknowledged by the `Dead` marking). Now my theories about what's wrong in this case:

1. it is somehow magically related to me not using `textField` delegate parameter. There is only one textfield in the controller and i spare a typecast, which may serve as a good intention but not justification.
2. the compiler had removed my check. In that case, i would like to know how to force it staying. It works in two other locations of the same app.
3. something else i haven't learned yet about this *Brave New Swift World*.

Ideas? Thanks.

**P.S. I forgot to add that this is an Appstore release crash report which we can't reproduce. I wouldn't be asking here if i could just simply debug it.**

Comment: You ever find out the solution to this? Can't seem to find a ton of info regarding Dead/Exploded etc or how to debug

Comment: It might be helpful for readers:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41155122/6600624